# Apache Spark Partitioning Data Using a SQL Function nTile

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying multiple ways to optimize executions of large datasets using partitioning. In particular I'm using a function commonly used with traditional SQL databases called nTile.

The objective is to place a certain number of rows into a bucket using a combination of buckettind and repartitioning. This allows Apache Spark to process data more efficient when processing partitioned datasets or should I say bucketted datasets.

Below is two examples. The first example shows how I've used ntile to split a dataset into two buckets followed by repartitioning the data into 2 partitions on the bucketted nTile called skew_data.

I then follow with the same query but without any bucketing or repartitioning.

The problem is query without the bucketting is faster then the query with bucketting, even the query without bucketting places all the data into one partition whereas the query with bucketting splits the query into 2 partitions.

Can someone let me know why that is.

FYI
I'm running the query on a Apache Spark cluster from Databricks.
The cluster just has one single node with 2 cores and 15Gb memory.

First example with nTile/Bucketting and repartitioning

```
allin = spark.sql("""
  SELECT
    t1.make
    , t2.model
    , NTILE(2) OVER (ORDER BY t2.sale_price) AS skew_data
  FROM 
    t1 INNER JOIN t2
    ON t1.engine_size = t2.engine_size2
""")
.repartition(2, col("skew_data"), rand())
.drop('skew_data')
```

The above code splits the data into partitions as follows, with the corresponding partition distribution

```
Number of partitions: 2
Partitioning distribution: [5556767, 5556797]
```

The second example: with no nTile/Bucketting or repartitioning

```
allin_NO_nTile = spark.sql("""
  SELECT
    t1.make
    ,t2.model
  FROM 
    t1 INNER JOIN t2
    ON t1.engine_size = t2.engine_size2
""")
```

The above code puts all the data into a single partition as shown below:

```
Number of partitions: 1
Partitioning distribution: [11113564]
```

My question is, why is it that the second query(without nTile or repartitioning) is faster than query with nTile and repartitioning?

I have gone to great lengths to write this question out as fully as possible, but if you need further explanation please don't hesitate to ask. I really want to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Whats the physical plan for the two queries? the second query has the potential to be a broadcast hashjoin whih would be faster than a sort merge join or a window function, which would require exchanging and sorting the data.

Comment: @AndrewLong, thanks for reaching out. I never got to the bottom of this question. However, I was pointed in the direction of using bucketBy() function instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned my original approached and used the new PySpark function called bucketBy(). If you want to know how to apply bucketBy() to bucket data go to
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dv7IIYuQOXI&list=PLOmMQN2IKdjvowfXo_7hnFJHjcE3JOKwu&index=39